# pygame.key.get_pressed() - doesn't work - pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, key, pygame

I have two problems with my program:

1. When I close my program it has error: `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() pygame.error: video system not initialized`
2. Square moves while I'm pressing 'd' and when I press something (or move mouse)

Important part of code is:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 700))
ticket1 = True

# ...

c = 550
d = 100

# ...

color2 = (250, 20, 20)

while ticket1 == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            ticket1 = False
            pygame.quit()
            pygame.display.quit()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            c += 1

    # ...

    screen.fill((255, 250, 245))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color2, pygame.Rect(c, d, 50, 75))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

If I write `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` in just while loop it doesn't have error but it seems slower.

I also have another error: `pygame.error: display Surface quit`, but I always and in all my pygame programs have it and it isn'n so important but other things are important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.--------------

After `pygame.quit()` you don't need `pygame.display.quit()` but `sys.exit()`. 
`pygame.quit()` doesn't exit program so program still try to call `screen.fill()` and other function below `pygame.quit()`

Or you have to put `pygame.quit()` outside `while ticket == True:` (and then you don't need `sys.exit()`)

You can use `while ticket1:` in place of `while ticket == True:` - it is more pythonic.

```
while ticket1: # it is more pythonic
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            ticket1 = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            c += 1

    # ...

    screen.fill((255, 250, 245))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color2, pygame.Rect(c, d, 50, 75))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

2.--------------

`if keys[pygame.K_d]: c += 1` is inside `for event` loop so it is call only when event is happend - when mouse is moving, when key is pressed or "unpressed". Move it outside of `for event` loop.

```
while ticket1: # it is more pythonic
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            ticket1 = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # outside of `for event` loop  
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        c += 1

    # ...

    screen.fill((255, 250, 245))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color2, pygame.Rect(c, d, 50, 75))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Some people do it without `get_pressed()`

```
# clock = pygame.time.Clock()
move_x = 0

while ticket1 == True:

    # events

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            ticket1 = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                ticket1 = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_x = 1

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_x = 0

    # variable modification

    c += move_x

    # ...

    # draws

    screen.fill((255, 250, 245))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color2, pygame.Rect(c, d, 50, 75))

    pygame.display.flip()

    # 60 FPS (Frame Per Second) to make CPU cooler

    # clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

---

BTW: use pygame.time.Clock() to get the same FPS on fast and slow computers. Without FPS program refresh screen thousends times per second so CPU is busy and hot.

If you use FPS you have to add to `c` bigger value to get the same speed then before.

Comment: It doesn't solve second problem:
Rect moves only if I press some key on keyboard or when i move mouse.
I need rect which moves when I press 'd'(pygame.K_d)

Comment: Check my answer again - see indentions.

Comment: It doesn't work with KEYUP but first method is pretty good.I have pygame.time.clock before but it isn't so important for problem.
P.S.:is clock.tick(80) to much?

Comment: For human eye it has to be at least 25. But most people use 60. TV set and monitor refresh screen with 60-120 (Hz). I thing 60-120 is enought.